# Using AJAX to post data into API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that uses AJAX to comunicate with PHP based API. 
First part loads trade history:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var orders = $('#History ul');
                var user = "<?php echo $user; ?>";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "api.php",
                    data: {
                        user: user
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        var res = JSON.parse(response);
                        $.each(res, function (index, value) {
                            console.log(value);
                            if(value['PL']>=0){
                            orders.append("<li style=\"color:green;\">" + value['User'] + "</li>");
                        }else{orders.append("<li style=\"color:red;\">" + value['User'] + "</li>");}
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Second part posts a trade to database:

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
                        //event.preventDefault();
                        var oPrice = newOrder.elements["oPrice"].value;
                        var cPrice = newOrder.elements["cPrice"].value;
                        var oType = newOrder.elements["oType"].value;;
                        var oSymbol = newOrder.elements["oSymbol"].value;
                        var oAmount = newOrder.elements["oAmount"].value;

                        var json ={
                            'user': user,
                            'oPrice': oPrice,
                            'cPrice': cPrice,
                            'oType': oType,
                            'oSymbol': oSymbol,
                            'oAmount': oAmount};

                        alert(JSON.stringify(json)); //---check zda je naplněný
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "api.php",
                            data: json,
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert(response);
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

The problem is, that when i press the button and send json, its missing the 'user' data and looks like this:

```
TraderBook.php?oPrice=1&cPrice=1&oType=LONG&oSymbol=1&oAmount=1
```

I have no idea why does ajax exclude it. The json variable has it filled out

Comment: May be var `user` is undefined?

Comment: It looks like a scoping problem with your user variable. Unless the event on submit is defined in the same ready function as the user var, it won't have access to it.

Comment: You need to pass the user variable into the click function or call it in.
You have already done this for your other values.

Comment: Is `#submit` a button or input of type submit inside a `form`???

Comment: @Roo But it would still post it, no?!

Comment: I already looked into that option. That is not the problem.. The variable gets passed down automaticaly and can be used in the click function.

Comment: And #submit is a button inside a form

Comment: @DominikMakovec BUT is it set inside a `form`? That's all the question!

Comment: @DominikMakovec have you logged your `user` variable inside the click function? Does it have a value?

Comment: @user3154108 yes it has a value

Comment: @DominikMakovec You still didn't answer my previous question**S**...  Is the button nested inside a `form` element??? If so instead of `$("#submit").click(function(){...});`, use: `$("#submit").closest('form').on('submit', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); /*rest of code here*/ });` otherwise you were posting the form's datas and probably wrong checking what's going on...

Comment: @DominikMakovec is the value an URL safe String? Useing GET method with try to convert data to url-safe strings, if that is not possible, drops them.

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry i edited my previous uncomplete answer.. yes its in a form i will try this out

Comment: @DominikMakovec My bad, i didn't see you edited previous comment. So i guess i'm correct regarding you check the data's posted form and not the data of POST request which anyway should be aborted

Comment: @A.Wolff yes you are correct there may be some error in the api

Comment: @DominikMakovec I forgot that you could just set type of button to `type="button"`, this way, it won't submit the `form` on click and so you could just keep all your posted code as it

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var user = "<?php echo $user; ?>";
```

`var` is the JS scoping declaration. So you're limiting your `user` value to just the anonymous function being triggered by the page DOM load completing. What you should do is try scoping it outside the function

```
var user; //global scope
$(document).ready(function () {
    user = "<?php echo $user; ?>";
```

This way, when your `$("#submit").click(function()` fires, there's a value to feed into your script.

Comment: OP said this isn't scope issue because `user` has got expected value. The issue seems just becaue OP was posting the `form` and `user` isn't a form's input so it isn't serialized

Answer (score 0):

I was wrongchecking the problem a mistook data from a form for the json. Problem was inside the API --> There was a tabulator in a SQL command..

Thanks to everyone for suggestions.